# How to install libraries with pear when no release is available

Tags: phpunit, pear

This is not the first time I experience something like that. This time it was with PHPunit.

I wanted to install the library using pear..

```
pear config-set auto_discover 1
pear install pear.phpunit.de/PHPUnit
```

The installation fails saying :

```
No releases available for package "pear.phpunit.de/PHPUnit"
```

What can I do ?

Thank you

Note :

pear upgrade says that I have the latest version

pear update-channels says that I am up to date

Note2 : I am at work so behing a proxy

Note3: using windows OS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it in another post.  the cache has to be cleared.

```
pear clear-cache
```

Answer (score 0):

In Windows Explorer, go to your WAMP PHP installation folder (default will be `C:\wamp\bin\php\php[version]`).
Create a new directory called `“PEAR”` here.
Download the PEAR phar installer https://phar.phpunit.de/phpunit.phar and place it in the new directory above.
Fire up a cmd window (Start and search for “cmd”) as administrator
Change to your new directory

```
(default command will be “cd C:\wamp\bin\php\php[version]\PEAR”)
```

Run the following command: `“php go-pear.phar”.`
The first thing that the installer will ask is whether you are installing a system wide copy of PEAR. Since you are probably working on a development machine, either is fine. Just press enter to install system wide.
Next, the installer will show you a bunch of paths that it automatically calculated by using it’s current location on your disc.

Comment: Sorry... forgot to say that I was with windows

Comment: I dont need to upgrade... my version seems to be the last as it says 1.9.4

Comment: I reinstalled but it does not change anything

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned you are behind a proxy, you may then need to set it explicitly, with something like the following:

```
$ pear config-set http_proxy http://username:password@proxy.example.com:80
```

Comment: I will try...though I am pretty sure we dont have the username and password (quite complicated) but when I have problem with the proxy, most of the time I have another message which is quite explicit about the fact that I cannot not reach the address... here it seems to be something else.